# Prevent Poisoned URL prefixes

Tags: .htaccess, dns

This morning I noticed that some results to our website have been poisoned in Google's search results. Our domain seems to have been prefixed with a rather bad url. Quite hard to describe this, but about 25 results on our domain seem to be formatted like this:

```
www.pornographicwebsite.com_www.ourdomain.com/

http://pornographicwebsite.com_www.ourdomain.com/
```

I suspect I need to setup some more rigid htaccess rules because the 'prefix' can be changed to anything and the URL will still load:

```
www.afisudfhsiudfhiasufd.com_www.ourdomain.com/

http://dfsdjflkjsafasjf.com_www.ourdomain.com/
```

Google Analytics is saving these URLs and it's really not appropriate considering the content of our website is aimed at children & parents

How can I block this sort of thing from happening please?

EDIT:
This is part of the config file as generated by plesk when the domain was added on our VPS:

```
<VirtualHost #.#.#.#:80>
   ServerName   ourdomain.com:80
   ServerAlias  www.ourdomain.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   ServerAdmin  "alex@ourdomain.com"
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/ourdomain.com/httpdocs

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I alter this to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.com/$1 [L]
```

this should redirect any domainname, other than www.ourdomain.com, to be redirected to www.ourdomain.com

Comment: Thanks Gerben. Can I also use that to allow 3 subdomains (static|api|dev) - would I simple use !^(www|static|api|dev).ourdomain.com in my htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives in the main Apache configuration file to list *exactly* those names you expect the server to respond to.

Any other name used will then result in a "404 error".

Comment: I've added a section of the config file as it was generated by Plesk originally. The server name & alias were already present.

Comment: odd - with that in place the server _shouldn't_ be answering for stuff sent with the other names.

Comment: Perhaps there is more to these configurations files. I have one 'default' entry for sites-available/enabled, and the main config files seems to read these plesk generates files in each of the respective domain vhost 'conf' directories. Perhaps I need to look elsewhere, or post the config file in its entirety?